# how to give engine values to django app for postgre instance that is on google cloud sql?

Tags: django, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I was working on heroku for my back-end and data storage. now due to some reasons i want to shift on google cloud sql. i am little bit confused that how i can give engine values in settings.py to access postgre instance. currently i am doing like this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'snr',#database name
        'USER': 'amad', #database user
        'PASSWORD': '1234',#database password
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/shopnroar-175407:us-central1:snr-instance1', #connection name
        'PORT': '5432', #port
    }
}
```

but it giving me error " File

```
"/home/amad/python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/amad/python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/amad/python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/amad/python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/amad/python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"

"
```

can somebody tell me how i can access that instance on google cloud sql from my local django app.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Obvious question, but does the username/password exist ?

Answer (score 0):

Error was in "Host". i put the ipv4 address of my instance in host. after that it working now.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx.xxx.xxx',
        'HOST': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```